# UI Component for Selecting Zero or One Item

Tags: html

On a website I want to present the user with a list of choices.  They can either choose zero or one choice at a given time.  What is the best form control to use for this?

A radio button list, enforces that one always be selected.

A checkbox list allows zero or many.

What's the common solution to this?  My thought is a checkbox list that does some validation when selected to clear everything else.

Thoughts?

Comment: Probably better to ask http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: wat R the choices? give an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use radio button control and add an "None" option to choose.